# I have the same number on 2 different phones with 2 different carriers

Tags: iphone, sim, cellular-carriers

I recently switched carriers and everything was done over the phone. I provided my account number etc from my old carrier to my new carrier and authorized everything to be transferred over.

I purchased a new sim card for my new carrier and placed it in my iPhone 6. When I called back to activate the iPhone 6 I called from my old iPhone 4, which was registered with my old carrier.

I expected as soon as the iPhone 6 was activated that the iPhone 4 with my old carrier would cut out, but it doesn't seem like this was the case. Now I have both phones connected to separate networks each using the same number and are fully functional.

I didn't think this was possible, does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Are you sure that they both use the same number (does it show the same number if you call another phone from both of them) or did you just forget to change the "own" phone number on the phone? If you call the number from a third phone, which of your phones rings?

Comment: @patrix I was able to make an outgoing call from both devices and the numbers were the same for both on the receiving end. When calling my number from another device, only the iPhone 6 is receiving the incoming call.

Answer (score 3):

When porting a number from one provider to another, it may take a few hours for the old network/provider to complete the process. If the situation still exists after a full business day, give the old provider a call to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment in answer to Patrix's question, it seems to me that your number **has ported correctly** across to your iPhone 6. This is why your iPhone 6 rings when someone calls your number, and why your iPhone 4 doesn't ring.

However, as you haven't reset your iPhone 4 you may need to change the My Number field. To do this:

- Go to Settings
- Tap on Phone
- Change the My Number field at the very top to the number it should be
- Exit Settings

If you haven't got a new different number for the iPhone 4, you need to get one if you intend to still use it as a phone.

However, you should reset the phone (especially if you're going to sell it). If you do intend to sell it or give it away, read [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351)!